# Rust installation fails. The command 'rustup-init -y' throws and error.

Tags: docker, rust, hyperledger-sawtooth, rustup

I am behind a corporate proxy and I'm trying to install Hyperledger Sawtooth on an Ubuntu machine.

Part of that setup is installing rust which is failing.

It uses the following command which is taken from a 'Dockerfile' file as part of the command `docker-compose up`:

`curl --insecure https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf > /usr/bin/rustup-init  && chmod +x /usr/bin/rustup-init  && rustup-init -y`

This gives me an error:

```
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
rustup: command failed: downloader https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/rustup-init /tmp/tmp.KEMZg5vZRK/rustup-init
```

Apparently, the command `rustup-init -y` is failing as I'm behind a corporate proxy and it failed to connect the url https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/rustup-init.

Where do I do the modification (add the -k flag) to turn off curl's certificate verification option so that I get an insecure connection and my installation is successful?

I tried modifying the rustup-init.sh file, but it is of no use.

Comment: Is installing `ca-certificates` not an option?

Comment: I tried installing `ca-certificates` too. Bu they don't seem to work.

Comment: Do you have the proxy credentials? You could then run `export https_proxy=https://user:password@your.proxy.server:port` before running curl.

Comment: I've set the proxy too. Both `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`